# Trying to read paginated asp pages with scrapy splash in python

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm attempting to use scrapy and splash to retrieve the Staff, job titles, and emails from a particular website's staff page. https://www.kennedaleisd.net/Page/3884. I'm using splash with docker since the emails are hidden behind dynamic javascript code.

The spider works on the first page of the staff however I can't seem to get it to work on the 2nd or 3rd pages. I opened up developer tools and have copied the request that is sent when you click on one of the pagination links and then attempted to replicate that request in the spider. The problem I appear to be having is that the response for that request only returns a sub-set of the code for the entire page (Just the staff for that page) instead of everything like the accompanying javascript. So when that is passed onto splash it doesn't have the necessary script to create the dynamic code. I also noticed that the request appeared to have a cookie entry of RedirectTo which goes back to the parent page. I had attempted including that cookie in the requests or passing cookies from the first request to the paginated pages, but it didn't seem to be working. I also attempted some lua scripts in the splash request but that didn't seem to be getting me what I wanted either. Below I've included the spider as I have it right now.

I'm not sure if there's some way to re-use the javascript with subsequent requests or to user that redict cookie in some way to get the rest of the needed code. Any help would be appreciated. I realize the pagination is probably not the proper way to loop through pages but I figured I could work on that once I get the reading of the data figured out.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'TestSpider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.kennedaleisd.net/Page/3884']

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse, meta={
                'splash': {
                    'endpoint': 'render.html',
                    'args': {'wait': 0.5}
                }
            })

    def parse(self, response):

        for item in response.css('div.staff'):

            name = item.css('li.staffname::text').get()
            title = item.css('li.staffjob::attr(data-value)').get()
            email = item.css('li.staffemail a::attr(href)').get()
            staffURL = response.request.url

            yield {
                'name': name,
                'title': title,
                'email': email,
                'staffURL': staffURL
            }

        if response.css('a.ui-page-number-current-span::text').get() == '1':
            pagination_results = response.css(
                'li.ui-page-number a:not([class^="ui-page-number-current-span"])::text').getall()

            base_url = 'https://www.kennedaleisd.net//cms/UserControls/ModuleView/ModuleViewRendererWrapper.aspx?DomainID=2042&PageID=3884&ModuleInstanceID=6755&PageModuleInstanceID=7911&Tag=&PageNumber='
            # backend_url = '&RenderLoc=0&FromRenderLoc=0&IsMoreExpandedView=false&EnableQuirksMode=0&Filter=&ScreenWidth=922&ViewID=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&_=1584114139549'

            for i in pagination_results:

                next_page = base_url + str(i)  # + backend_url

                yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse, meta={
                    'splash': {
                        'endpoint': 'render.html',
                        'args': {'wait': 3}
                    }
                })
```

Comment: There's probably a way to do it with lua, but I would just switch to selenium if I were you.

Comment: I was wanting to avoid using a ton of libraries and especially anything that'll require user input. I will look into selenium though to see if it would be useful should no other suggestions come up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a bit of tinkering I figured out how to handle this with the lua script I had been toying with. I'd still much prefer a different method if there is something that is a bit more official rather than using scripting.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

script_frontend = """
function main(splash)
  splash:init_cookies(splash.args.cookies)
  assert(splash:go{
    splash.args.url,
    headers=splash.args.headers,
    http_method=splash.args.http_method,
    body=splash.args.body,
    })
  assert(splash:wait(3))

  assert(splash:select('#ui-paging-container > ul > li:nth-child("""

script_backend = """) > a'):mouse_click())
  assert(splash:wait(3))

  local entries = splash:history()
  local last_response = entries[#entries].response
  return {
    url = splash:url(),
    headers = last_response.headers,
    http_status = last_response.status,
    cookies = splash:get_cookies(),
    html = splash:html(),
  }
end
"""

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'TestSpider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.kennedaleisd.net/Page/3884']

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse, meta={
                'splash': {
                    'endpoint': 'render.html',
                    'args': {'wait': 0.5}
                }
            })

    def parse(self, response):

        for item in response.css('div.staff'):

            name = item.css('li.staffname::text').get()
            title = item.css('li.staffjob::attr(data-value)').get()
            email = item.css('li.staffemail a::attr(href)').get()
            staffURL = response.request.url

            yield {
                'name': name,
                'title': title,
                'email': email,
                'staffURL': staffURL
            }

        if response.css('a.ui-page-number-current-span::text').get() == '1':
            pagination_results = response.css(
                'li.ui-page-number a:not([class^="ui-page-number-current-span"])::text').getall()

            for i in pagination_results:

                script = script_frontend + str(i) + script_backend

                yield SplashRequest(self.start_urls[0], self.parse,
                                    endpoint='execute',
                                    cache_args=['lua_source'],
                                    args={'lua_source': script},
                                    headers={'X-My-Header': 'value'},
                                    session_id='foo'
                                    )
```